# Increase JOIN Query response time by combining tables

Tags: mysql, sql, join, optimization, lag

We have a sports shopping website that recommends products to users. our query recommends by doing a JOIN on three tables of the following effect: (1)  what sports a user is interested in, (2) what products are part of that sport, and (3) eliminate products the user has already bought. We have three tables currently. The response time is 3 seconds.

In an effort to make the query response faster, we are proposing combing two tables into one table . The attached image shows the proposed logic. My question is:

1. is the proposed query even possible as a **single** query
2. **if all else is equal**, will the proposed logic be faster than the current logic - even if it is a small amount?

We are on AWS MySQL RDS. All indexes have been done correctly. Please don't discuss about migrating to Redis, MEMSql etc, i am just interested at this stage to understand if the proposed logic will be faster.

Thank you for your help!!

[image: Proposed Query Change]

**CREATEs**

```
CREATE TABLE UserPreferences (
    UserPreferenceId int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
    UserId int(11) NOT NULL, 
    FamilyId int(11) NOT NULL, 
    InsertedDate datetime NOT NULL, 
    PRIMARY KEY (UserPreferenceId), 
    KEY userID (UserId), 
    KEY FamilyId (FamilyId), 
    KEY user (UserId), 
    KEY fk_UserPreferences_1 (FamilyId), 
) ENGINE=InnAoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=261 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
CREATE TABLE ArticleToFamily (
    ArticleToFamilyId int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
    ArticleId int(11) DEFAULT NULL, 
    FamilyId int(11) unsigned NOT NULL, 
    InsertedDate datetime DEFAULT NULL, 
    Confidence int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0', 
    Rank int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0', 
    PRIMARY KEY ArticleToFamilyId),
    KEY ArticleIdAndFamilyId` (ArticleId,FamilyId), 
    KEY FamilyId (FamilyId)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=19795572 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
CREATE TABLE ItemsUserHasBought (
    ItemsUserHasBoughtId int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
    UserId int(11) NOT NULL, 
    ArticleId int(11) NOT NULL, 
    BuyDate datetime NOT NULL, 
    InsertedDate datetime NOT NULL, 
    UpdatedDate datetime NOT NULL, 
    Status char(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1', 
    PRIMARY KEY (ItemsUserHasBoughtId), 
    KEY ArticleId (ArticleId)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=367 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Comment: Edit the question and include the query you are using *as text*.

Comment: Also indexes on the tables.

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for the 3 tables.  3 seconds sounds like you have a big table without suitable indexes.

Comment: @RickJames 
CREATE TABLE `UserPreferences` (
  `UserPreferenceId` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `UserId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `FamilyId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `InsertedDate` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`UserPreferenceId`),
  KEY `userID` (`UserId`),
  KEY `FamilyId` (`FamilyId`),
  KEY `user` (`UserId`),
  KEY `fk_UserPreferences_1` (`FamilyId`),
) ENGINE=InnAoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=261 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8

Comment: CREATE TABLE `ArticleToFamily` (
  `ArticleToFamilyId` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `ArticleId` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `FamilyId` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `InsertedDate` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `Confidence` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `Rank` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY ArticleToFamilyId`),
  KEY `ArticleIdAndFamilyId` (`ArticleId`,`FamilyId`),
  KEY `FamilyId` (`FamilyId`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=19795572 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1

Comment: CREATE TABLE `ItemsUserHasBought` (
  `ItemsUserHasBoughtId` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `UserId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `ArticleId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `BuyDate` datetime NOT NULL,
  `InsertedDate` datetime NOT NULL,
  `UpdatedDate` datetime NOT NULL,
  `Status` char(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  PRIMARY KEY (`ItemsUserHasBoughtId`),
  KEY `ArticleId` (`ArticleId`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=367 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1

Answer (score 2):

Don't do it.

Combining tables usually means denormalization of some kind, which is not the direction you want to be moving in a relational database. It's rarely side-effect free and often fails to achieve the desired gains. All in all, something to avoid, to be done only when all other avenues are exhausted.

Instead, check your indexes on the three tables that you have. It's likely that adding a foreign key in the right place can easily make this query run in a fraction of it's current time. Unfortunately, until we know what indexes you're already using, we can't be any more specific about how to improve it. It's also possible you're doing the right things here, and are really hitting a wall in terms of what your server is able to do... but probably not.

If indexes don't help, the next place I'd usually look is a materialized/indexed view. This is supported by Sql Server, Oracle, Postgresql, and most other modern database server engines. Sadly, like Windowing Functions, the APPLY/lateral join operation, and correct NULL handling, indexed views are among the many parts of ansi sql where MySql lags behind other dbs. MySql is sadly becoming more and more of a joke with each passing year... but then that's probably all part of Oracle's plan since the Sun acquisition. If you really want an open source DB, Postgresql has outclassed MySql for years now in pretty much every category. MySql is living now off of it's old momentum; it's popular because it's *been* popular, and is therefore widely available among the low-cost web hosts, but not at all because it's better.

Don't get me wrong: MySql used to be a *great* option. Postgresql hardly existed, and Oracle and Sql Server weren't any better back then and priced out of reach for most small businesses. But Oracle, Sql Server, Postgresql, and others have all moved on in ways that MySql hasn't. Postgresql, specifically, has gotten easier to manage while MySql has lost some of the simplicity that gave it an advantage, without picking up enough features that really matter.

But anyone can be an armchair architect, and I've editorialized way too  much already. Given wholesale database change isn't likely to be an option for you by now anyway, take a long close look at your indexes. It's a good bet you'll be able to fix your problem that way. And if you can't, you can always throw more hardware at your server. Because MySql is cheaper, right?

Comment: Thats what i thought. I'll also look at the foreign key option. Thanks for your insight.